# 3 instances errors; how to fix them?

Tags: haskell

```
type Politico = (String, Int, String, Anteriores)
type Anteriores = [(Int, Bool)]
type Distrito = (String, Int, [String])
type Encuestador = Distrito

alnarvin = ("Raul De Alnarvín", 45, "CPU",[(2003, False), (1999, False), (2009, True)])
fernando = ("Elisa Fernando", 56, "PNG",[ (2003, True), (2005, True), ( 2007, False)] )
rodriguezSolana = ("Ernesto Rodriguez Solana", 49, "FPS", [(2009,True)])
altamirano = ("Daniel Altamiarno", 60, "POO",[ (2003, False), (2005, False), ( 2007, False) ])
carcaman = ("Antonio Francisco Carcaman", 90, "JPG",[(1956, True), (1960, True), (1980, True), (1995, False)])


--PARTE A. JUBILACIONES

coeficienteVictorias:: Politico -> Int
coeficienteVictorias politico  
 |(cantidadDeEleccionesALasQueSePresento /= 0) = (cantidadDeVecesQueGano politico) / (cantidadDeEleccionesALasQueSePresento politico)
 |otherwise = 0

-- FUNCIONES AUXILIARES

eleccionesAnteriores :: Politico -> Anteriores
eleccionesAnteriores (_,_,_, eleccionesAnteriores) = eleccionesAnteriores

cantidadDeEleccionesALasQueSePresento :: Politico -> Int
cantidadDeEleccionesALasQueSePresento politico = (length.eleccionesAnteriores) politico

cantidadDeVecesQueGano :: Politico -> Int
cantidadDeVecesQueGano politico = length (filter snd (map eleccionesAnteriores politico))
```

Errors:

```
tp haskell.hs:9:49:
No instance for (Eq (Politico -> Int))
  arising from a use of `/='
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Eq (Politico -> Int))
In the expression: (cantidadDeEleccionesALasQueSePresento /= 0)
In a stmt of a pattern guard for
               an equation for `coeficienteVictorias':
  (cantidadDeEleccionesALasQueSePresento /= 0)
In an equation for `coeficienteVictorias':
    coeficienteVictorias politico
      | (cantidadDeEleccionesALasQueSePresento /= 0)
      = div
          (cantidadDeVecesQueGano politico)
          (cantidadDeEleccionesALasQueSePresento politico)
      | otherwise = 0

tp haskell.hs:9:52:
No instance for (Num (Politico -> Int))

  arising from the literal `0'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Num (Politico -> Int))
In the second argument of `(/=)', namely `0'
In the expression: (cantidadDeEleccionesALasQueSePresento /= 0)
In a stmt of a pattern guard for
               an equation for `coeficienteVictorias':
  (cantidadDeEleccionesALasQueSePresento /= 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the second half of the first error says,

```
In the expression: (cantidadDeEleccionesALasQueSePresento /= 0)
In a stmt of a pattern guard for
               an equation for `coeficienteVictorias':
  (cantidadDeEleccionesALasQueSePresento /= 0)
In an equation for `coeficienteVictorias':
    coeficienteVictorias politico
      | (cantidadDeEleccionesALasQueSePresento /= 0)
      = div
          (cantidadDeVecesQueGano politico)
          (cantidadDeEleccionesALasQueSePresento politico)
      | otherwise = 0
```

The problem is at

```
(cantidadDeEleccionesALasQueSePresento /= 0)
```

You forgot to apply the "cantidad" function to `politico`. The "no instance" part...

```
No instance for (Eq (Politico -> Int))
  arising from a use of `/='
```

... means that you can't test a function, like `cantidadDeEleccionesALasQueSePresento`, for (in)equality. This should work:

```
coeficienteVictorias:: Politico -> Int
coeficienteVictorias politico  
    | cantidadDeEleccionesALasQueSePresento politico /= 0 =
        cantidadDeVecesQueGano politico / cantidadDeEleccionesALasQueSePresento politico
    | otherwise = 0
```

N.B.: You probably don't need to deal with that right now (it is better to go one step at each time), but using `length` twice to calculate the ratio is rather inefficient, as you have to run through the list at least twice (three times counting the filtering). A better solution would be using a fold (such as `foldl'` from `Data.List`) to do it all in one pass.

Answer (score 0):

The good thing about GHC compilation errors is that they're actually (mostly) very good to help you get  the job done.

Let's look at instances in a bit, but first start off with:

```
No instance for (Eq (Politico -> Int))
  arising from a use of `/='
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Eq (Politico -> Int))
In the expression: (cantidadDeEleccionesALasQueSePresento /= 0)
```

That's GHC telling you, that there's some problem in the last expression. It's asking you to do something on `Eq (Politico -> Int)`. That's the best quick-read clue when you're debugging. 
Is that type signature something that should be causing a bug for that expression?

If you look at `cantidadDeEleccionesALasQueSePresento` it's actually a function with `Politico -> Int` as its type signature.

Which clearly means it's something that you can't do a `/= 0` operation on. So the immediate correction would be to change  `cantidadDeEleccionesALasQueSePresento`  to  `cantidadDeEleccionesALasQueSePresento politico`.

**The `instances` business**

It helps to think of Haskell as types, typeclasses and functions. You have values in the language. Each value is of some type. Each type can derive some typeclasses. Typeclasses are sort of like certain properties that a value of that type has. `Eq Show Ord` are properties that denote Equality, 'Print-ablity' and Ordering. `Int String` are two types whose values obey that property. You can make your own types and ensure that they obey those typeclasses (usually by just adding a `derive` statement).

`/=` is a function that operates on things that have the `Eq` class. 
What GHC is telling you, is that it has encountered a value that doesn't have the Equality property. It's telling you that this value is of the `Politico -> Int` type. That sort of a type denotes a function. It makes sense that this can't be equated to 0 now.

Don't get too bogged down by the length of the error message. The most important lines are just the first few that tell you the line number and the offending expression. The rest is to help you quickly locate the exact parent expression.